# Row expands its height due to toggle button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[[image: output of the codeHow the grid looks]

My problem is that in the 2nd row the toggle button appears good in design view but when i run the project it expands the height of the row automatically. I have also tried placing the toggle button inside a viewbox in the grid but it does not work. Can anyone please help me in this problem. if i give the margin to the toggle button or the viewbox inside the style it reduces the size of the toggle button but the expansion problem of the row remains same.

Piece of code--------`

```css
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" ></ColumnDefinition>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" ></ColumnDefinition>




        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >

            <Border BorderBrush="#1B5E6E" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="8" />
            <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="#1B5E6E" ></Canvas>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Experiment" Background="#1B5E6E" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" TextElement.FontSize="9" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#EAEAEA" Margin="2,0,2,0" >
                <Viewbox   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
                    <Label      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Project" Cursor="Hand" TextElement.FontSize="9"  TextElement.FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  >
                        <Label.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />

                            </Style>
                        </Label.Style>
                    </Label>
                </Viewbox>
            </Canvas>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

            <Canvas Grid.Row="3" Background="#EAEAEA" Margin="2,0,2,0" ></Canvas>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Series"  TextElement.FontSize="9"  VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

            <Canvas Grid.Row="5" Background="#EAEAEA" Margin="2,0,2,0" ></Canvas>
            <Label Grid.Row="5" Content="Experiment"  TextElement.FontSize="9"  VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

            <Canvas Grid.Row="7" Background="#EAEAEA" Margin="2,0,2,0" ></Canvas>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>





        </Grid>


        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="#EAEAEA" >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.40*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border BorderBrush="#1B5E6E" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="#1B5E6E" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></Canvas>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Process Steps" Background="#1B5E6E" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" TextElement.FontSize="9" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   ></Label>

            <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#EAEAEA" Margin="2,0,2,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></Canvas>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="1 - Grundeinstellung"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="2 - Vorheizen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="3 - Beladen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="4 - Heizen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="5 - Messen vor umformen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Content="6 - Umformen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Content="7 - Entformen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Content="8 - Messen nach umformen"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Content="9 - Verfahren"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Content="10 - Leerlauf"  TextElement.FontSize="9"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Label>


            <!--<Viewbox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  >
                <mah:ToggleSwitch     >
                    
                </mah:ToggleSwitch>
            </Viewbox>-->


            <ToggleButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"   >
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Viewbox  Margin="14.4,4.8,23.8,6.6" >
                                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
                            Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                            Width="40" Height="20">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                            <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
                                 Margin="2 1 2 1"
                                 Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                <Ellipse.Effect>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                                                </Ellipse.Effect>
                                            </Ellipse>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FF4CD661"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                        To="20 1 2 1"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="White"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                        To="2 1 2 1"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>








        </Grid>





        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.4*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post the XAML for the grid too? Do you have any styles for toggle button in your resources?

Comment: @Charleh I have updated the post and also have included the code for grid. No i am not using any styles for toggle button in my resources

Comment: @FarrukhTanveer  What kind of Environment is this? 
I grapped your XAML and dropped it into some Window1.xaml
But the rows just grow and shrink unifomly when you resize the window.
Also the toggle button resizes, but it doesnt effect its row height...

It tested on Win7 x64 Desktop NET 5 VS 2019 (16.10.0)

Comment: @FarrukhTanveer Ìfi I set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` or `SizeToContent="Height"` for the Window I can reproduce it.
Also you have a surrounding Grid (Code not shown) which might effect measurement.

Comment: @lidqy I have updated the code. Can you please check

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with the same steps as @lidqy ??

Comment: @Charleh if i use the above given code which contains a nested grid then the toggle button causes problem. if i use just use the grid that contains the toggle button separately, then it works fine.